# Banshee package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: package-management

For some reason I cannot play any mp3 files with banshee. I get `codec for playing this media type not available`.

[image]

If I press `install multimedia plugins` I get this:

[image]

I tried reinstalling Banshee completely but it did not help. I also checked everything single topic on Stackexchange about this, but nothing worked.

Comment: Please add the output of the command below to your question: `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'`

Comment: Well @Gasp0de's  answer solved my problem, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to install both the 64-bit version of gstreamer-ugly as well as the 32-bit version at the same time. This is not possible, due to their conflicting dependencies. Try to install only one of the two packages, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly if you have a 64-bit OS, and gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly (i386) if you have a 32-bit OS

Comment: Yep this solved, so simple and i was googling for ages! Thank you sir